# Add a check-box when running Wix Boostrapper Uninstall

Tags: wix, burn

At the moment when I uninstall my application it brings up a WiX burn dialog saying "Modify Setup" and gives me 3 buttons: Repair, Uninstall, and Close

What I would like is to add a check-box to this screen or alternatively to another page that follows the user clicking "uninstall".

If it makes a difference, if checked I will perform a full uninstall (remove all settings, databases etc) - I imagine this is a fairly common scenario but have not had any luck in finding examples.

The closest I seem to have got so far is this Wix page on [building a custom bootstrapper](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/ba/) but it seems to lack a lot of information. It seems that I'd have to build the whole boostrapper myself (rather than insert a single check-box).

Thanks guys & gals!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you should accept the answer

Comment: A good point. I hate it when people don't accept an answer !! 
It's only 2 years ago, but I think that I didn't get a chance to try it in the end (if you look at my comment), so I simply upvoted as a thanks for the response but don't want to mislead by accepting as that would infer it worked, which I haven't verified ... I really should try it - if for no other reason than being able to accept the answer!! I appreciate the prod though :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.  I think you're looking for something more along the lines of [this page](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_customize.html).

In your theme file in the Modify page, add a checkbox.  The name of the checkbox will be used for the bundle Variable name, something like this:

```
<Checkbox Name="DoFullUninstall" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.DoFullUninstall)</Checkbox>
```

Then maybe you're passing that to an MSI?  So in the bundle .wxs:

```
<MsiProperty Name="DOFULLUNINSTALL" Value="[DoFullUninstall]" />
```

Comment: Looks great. Thanks. It would appear that it's not simple to just delete a directory of one's choice on uninstall based on a condition...may be a while before I get a proper chance to give this a whirl.

I have yet to discover something straightforward in WiX :(